# Bash - How to retrieve all names file of a directory?

Tags: php, bash

I need to get all filename in a directory

Example (in PHP)

```
$filenames = array();

foreach($filenames as $filename)
{
   Execute('sh testname.sh $filename'); 
}
```

1)How to get $filenames array?

2) How to translate this in Batch?

Comment: "batch" or "bash"? "Names" doesn't need an apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *
do
  sh "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it too - using PHP.  You can specify what types of file you want by messing about with the * part

```
$files = glob("/tmp/*");

foreach($files as $file) {

  echo "{$file}\n";

}
```